# Chicken Scheme interpreter arrow key not working

Tags: chicken-scheme

I have installed Chicken Scheme on WSL debain Linux.
I can run chicken Scheme interpreter from command line.
but arrow key just not work.

up arrow ^[[A
down arrow ^[[B

here is a screen shot

[image]

Comment: Not sure if `rlwrap` works on **WSL**, but try installing `readline-devel` package and then try running ... `rlwrap csi` and after which your arrow keys should be fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a [FAQ](https://wiki.call-cc.org/faq#does-csi-support-history-and-autocompletion).  Basically, CHICKEN tries to be relatively minimalistic out of the box, so there's no line editing feature bundled with the core distribution.

You probably want to install the [breadline egg](https://wiki.call-cc.org/eggref/5/breadline) and set up your `.csirc` to load it (see the [example](https://depp.brause.cc/breadline/examples/.csirc)).

Alternatively, use `rlwrap`, which can add line editing capability to any program which lacks it.